# how to use command line to execute exe file in vb vs2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, batch-file, command-line

i have a exe file , which must be opened with a command line

```
start a.exe /stext d:/alpha.txt
```

to save a file in d drive. I tried creating a batch file and calling it in vb but the batch dosent  executes the exe file, so is there any direct method to add command line in vb to run the exe file to generate the alpha text.

Comment: Have a look at Process.Start()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Process Name)
```